# Is this a pun? "Der wird sie einmal heiraten -- so sogt er"

Tags: meaning

From [Georg Kreisler](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Kreisler)'s [Der General](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdxuEbA6-rU):

> Die erste ist verheiratet, ich glaub, mit a Chauffeur. 
>   Die zweite ist sogar mit einem Doktor. 
>   Der wird sie einmal heiraten -- so sogt er. 
>   (*laughter from the audience*)

Is this a pun between *sagt* and *sogt*? If so what's funny about *sogt*? If not, where is the pun?

I realise that I'm not going to find the explained pun very fun, but then I'll at least be able to laugh with good conscience.

Comment: I love your questions!

Comment: Quote starts here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdxuEbA6-rU&t=2m47s

Comment: Für die, die nicht so gut Englisch können: Pun bedeutet Wortspiel.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's not a pun, just Viennese dialect for "sagt" (as Kreisler was a popular singer and comedian from Vienna).

The funny part of that line is that the doctor will probably never marry that girl - instead, he'll move on to the next girl and promise marriage to her.

Comment: This. The pun probably works in every culture on the planet. :)

Comment: Aha! I was convinced that it was liposuction-related.

Comment: @Tim lol, nope. I think that line is way too old for anything liposuction-related :-)

Answer (score 6):

There's nothing specifically funny about *sogt*, that's just the accent (he chose to use for this song).

The joke is in *how* he delivers the line: chatty, not sung, somewhat too easygoing. The doctor *says* he has plans to marry the girl, but the way he is delivering that line implies that it's not a very high priority and the doctor is probably skipping over the subject whenever asked.

> Jaja, ich werd sie schon heiraten, keine Sorge...

Which implies that it's probably not going to happen.

Answer (score 5):

"So sogt er" sounds to the south of Germany.

I would explain it different. "Der wird sie einmal heiraten" is first a statement that this doctor will really marry. The sentence "so sogt er" is to introduce a restriction in the narrator's skepticism - he will never marry her.

Answer (score 2):

Also, it produces a rhyme:

> ... Doktor
>
> ... sogt er

The High German variant does not rhyme:

> ... Doktor
>
> ... sagt er